# Apply logsumexp to all the first element of array

Tags: python, scipy

I have a question, under a specific variable that for semplicitity we call a, I have the following arrays written in this way.

```
[-6.396736847188359, -6.154559100742114, -6.211476547612676]
[-8.006589632001111, -7.826171257487284, -7.71335303949824]
[-6.456557174187878, -6.262447971939394, -6.38657184063457]
[-7.487923068341583, -7.189375715312779, -7.252991999097159]
[-7.532980499994895, -7.44329050097094, -7.529773039725542]
[-7.429923219897081, -6.960840780894108, -7.173489030350187]
[-7.194082458487091, -6.909676564074833, -6.944666159195248]
[-7.734357883680035, -7.512036612219159, -7.607808831503251]
[-7.734008421702387, -7.164880777772352, -7.709697714174302]
[-8.3156235828106, -8.486948182913475, -8.612390113851397]
```

How can I apply the scipy formula logsumexp to each column? I tried to use the logsumexp(a[0]) but it doesn't work also I try to iterate over a[0] but i got the error about flot64.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  `axis` parameter: `logsumexp(a, axis=?)`, where ? Is 0 or 1

Comment: By doing this I will have as an output an array with three values one for each column?